# React use True/False for .filter.map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter, jsx

I have a site, where i want so filter my pictures via tags.
the filter is made with checkboxes, which are generated by the tags themselves.

i break down the code to the nessessary:

```js
   const [filteredTags, setFilteredTags] = useState();
    // {wedding: false, couple: true, NSWF: true}  <-this is the ouput of console.log(filteredTags)

const PortfolioData= [
    {
      name: "John & Johna ",
      tag: ["wedding", "couple"],
      img: [ src1 , src2, ...] //irrelevant
    },
    {
      name: "Mario & Marie",
      tag: ["couple", "NSFW"],
      img: [ src1 , src2, ...] //irrelevant
    },
  ];

return(
<>
 {PortfolioData
            .filter(visible => visible.tag.includes( ??????? )) //<- what to write ?
            .map((PortfolioData) => {                    
              return (
                <Tile                                        
                  header={PortfolioData.name}
                  imgSrc={PortfolioData.mainImg[0]}
                />
              );
            })}


</>
)
```

How can I filter this?

Comment: What combination do you want? Must all `true`s be present, or only at least one `true`?

Comment: @CertainPerformance
 at least one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that `.some` of the tags being iterated over are truthy in the `filteredTags` object. (To make things easier to manage, it'd be good to set `filteredTags` to also have an initial value of an empty object, and not `undefined`)

```
const [filteredTags, setFilteredTags] = useState({});
// for TypeScript:
// const [filteredTags, setFilteredTags] = useState<Record<string, boolean | undefined>>({});
```

```
{PortfolioData
  .filter(collection => collection.tag.some(tag => filteredTags[tag]))
```

Comment: i got the error filteredTags is undefindet, so I changed `useState()` to `useState('')`. Now After that I got an error because of the `[tag]`  _Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'._

Comment: It's working, but now i have to figure it out, how so satisfy Typescript

Comment: Tell TS that the object is of type `Record<string, boolean | undefined>` - see the generic syntax in the answer - does that work for you?

Comment: You're a magician!  Thx !